# command line msbuild with multiple DefineConstants

Tags: powershell, batch-file, syntax, msbuild

From powershell

```
Set-Alias msbuild C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

and running from the same directory as my sln file

```
> msbuild /nologo /property:DefineConstants=FOO
```

works just fine. Let's say I need two build time constants though.

```
> msbuild /nologo /property:DefineConstants=FOO;BAR
```

Powershell interprets the semi-colon as an end-of-statement and runs with a single constant and then tries to run the command `BAR` and errors. So not what I want.

How about?

```
> msbuild /nologo /property:DefineConstants="FOO;BAR"
MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: BAR
```

This doesn't work either. Not sure what's going on here but it seems to be interpreting "FOO;BAR" as some sort of single thing - not two constants.

So. How do I actually pass in multiple constants?

**Edit**
Upon further investigation, I'm running the following in cmd.exe

```
>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo /property:DefineConstants=FOO;BAR
MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: BAR
```

although this works

```
>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo /property:DefineConstants="FOO;BAR"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ideas:

Add quotes around the property flag and escape the double quotes

```
msbuild /nologo "/property:DefineConstants=`"FOO;BAR`""
```

Use the call operator `&` (works in PS v4+)

```
& msbuild /nologo /property:DefineConstants="FOO;BAR"
```

Comment: Should be noted that while this works for the `DefineConstants` property it breaks for stuff that takes paths if the path contains a space. So in that case do not use this trick.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer String escaping for command line tools is one of the areas where powershell can be difficult to use. I noticed that the second option was working for me on version 4.0 but not version 3.0.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Can you give an example for the case with a path with a space? Are you talking about setting a property to a path with a space or just a path to a proj/sln file?

Comment: In my build script I just tried escaping all `/property:...` as you suggested, and that didn't work since some of them were for things like `OutDir`. Only escaping the `DefineConstants` clause worked fine

Comment: You could try using single quotes on the paths, something like `msbuild "/OutDir:'\path\to the\output'"`.

Comment: Actually you can just quote the whole property so eg `msbuild /nologo "/property:OutDir=c:\My Secret Apps\bin" "/property:DefineConstants=\`"FOO;BAR\`"`

Comment: Constants separated by simple space character may be used as well: `"/p:DefineConstants=FOO BAR"`

Answer (score 8):

We can use msbuild escape characters as msbuild /t:rebuild "/property:DefineConstants=PROD%3BCODE_ANALYSIS". Where %3B is to use ; in properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228186.aspx

Comment: surprisingly, this only worked for me when using xbuild (it fails with msbuild)

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions above worked for me so I had to employ another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32326853/544947