# How to merge constants of command line and constants of configuration

Tags: msbuild

I have a project with a preprocessor constant defined for a configuration

```
<DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;VAR1</DefineConstants>
```

My code could be :

```
#if VAR1
        Console.WriteLine("Var1");
#endif
#if VAR2
        Console.WriteLine("Var2");
#endif
```

I want execute MSBuild and define the constant VAR2 without override constants defined in the configuration

I try :

```
MSBuild MyProject.csproj /p:DefineConstants=VAR2
```

But constants defined in the project file are not set : my program displays only

> Var2

I have tried things like without success :

```
MSBuild MyProject.csproj /p:DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants);VAR2
```

or

```
<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);TRACE;DEBUG;VAR1</DefineConstants>
```

Is it a way to merge the constants defined in the project and constants defined on the command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK a property defined via commandline will always override a statically defined property with the same name. As a workaround you can enqueue an additional property to `<DefineConstants />` that is not defined in your project file:

```
<DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;VAR1;$(MyCommandLineConstants)</DefineConstants>
```

and call MSBuild this way:

```
MSBuild MyProject.csproj /p:MyCommandLineConstants=VAR2;VAR3
```

Comment: this actually doesn't work, it gives `MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid`