# Why does MSBuild fails to find my constant in Directory.Build.props?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to use a [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) file to define a simple preprocessor constant for to my solution.

For testing purposes I created a console application (C#) and added a *Directoy.Build.props* file right next to the generated *.csproj* file:

```
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
       <DefineConstants>TEST1</DefineConstants>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I also manually edited the *.csproj* itself to test the `<DefineConstants>` actually works:

```
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;TEST2;</DefineConstants>
```

Now the actual code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
#if TEST1
    // NOT WORKING!
    Console.WriteLine("<DefineConstants>TEST1</DefineConstants> in Directory.Build.props"); // NOT WORKING!
#else
    Console.WriteLine("failed TEST1 in Directory.Build.props");
#endif

#if TEST2
     // WORKS!
     Console.WriteLine("<DefineConstants>TEST2</DefineConstants> in csproj"); // WORKS!
#else
     Console.WriteLine("failed TEST2 in csproj");
#endif

    }
```

So why does MSBuild fails to find my constant in Directory.Build.props?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793499/defineconstants-in-addition-to-existing-ones-in-csproj, I'm guessing that the same thing applies with Directory.build.props.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren OH wow! that did it! but is there a way it will happen automatically without manually editing the csproj?

Comment: Using `<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants), ..</DefineConstants>` may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should note that `Directory.Build.props` file is imported at the begin of the csproj file. In your side, because the imported property is too early to be overridden, it is overridden by `defineConstants` in **CSProj**.

So `Directory.Build.props` is usually used to define global properties while `Directory.Build.targets` is to overwrite the properties.

[image]

[Check this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#import-order).

So you should use to overwrite the property.

**Solutions**

I have two solutions for you:

**1)** rename your `Directory.Build.props` to `Directory.Build.targets` and ensure these on the file:

```
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
       <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TEST1</DefineConstants>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Make sure that csproj file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;TEST2;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**2)** remain the file as `Directory.Build.props` and keep its content as:

```
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
       <DefineConstants>TEST1</DefineConstants>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

change your csproj file to:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;TEST2;$(DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: thanks! I might end up using the first option you suggested.

Comment: This is great! MSBuild is such a lovely tech... Any idea why this may not work? The only difference I have is that I have the `Directory.Build.targets` in solution directory. But from what I read I understand it should work.