dotnet app isn't recognizing compilation symbol defined in csproj
I have a .NET 8 app which uses a custom conditional compilation symbol as follows:
#if MY_SYMBOL
    public MyConstructor() : base(ArgumentOne) { }
#else
    public MyConstructor() : base(ArgumentTwo) 
    {
        throw new Exception("A compilation-time tier symbol must be set");
    }
#endif

I am finding that if I pass my symbol to the dotnet run command as the DefineConstants property like this - dotnet run -p:DefineConstants=MY_SYMBOL - then it works fine (code is compiled with the first constructor).
However, if I do this in my csproj file like this...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_SYMBOL</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

...then run the app in debug mode using a launch profile, the symbol isn't set so the code is compiled with the second constructor above.
What is the reason for this? I'm trying to achieve a scenario where I have a default symbol in my local dev environment, then pass a custom symbol via dotnet run in my Dockerfile for deploy environments. Is there a better, more reliable approach?

See the question(s) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793499/defineconstants-in-addition-to-existing-ones-in-csproj.

It isn't clear to me how this addresses my question..?

All you need in your .csproj file is a line in the form <DefineConstants>MY_SYMBOL</DefineConstants>. If you want to define more than one symbol then just include the extra ones, separated by semi-colons: something like <DefineConstants>SYMBOL1;SYMBOL2; ...</DefineConstants>. There is an example in the MSDN documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language.

Yes, and as per my question you can see I'm doing this, yet when I run the application from VS using a launch profile the symbol is not being detected.

You need to show your entire .csproj file so we can see if there is anything wrong. I have tried a number of different combinations and cannot get it to fail.
