Enrich logging with application type in .NET (console, web app, service)
I'm looking for a way to detect the current application type in C#. I provide a library that should try to determine whether the current application is an ASP.NET Core web app, a console application, a Windows Service, etc. Does anyone know a good way to do this?
Before anyone says "You shouldn't create code dependent on the application type" and so on. Agree, this is not the purpose here. I want to enrich some logging data with the application type. My code will not differ depending on the application type.
I was thinking of creating a method to return the type after looking at various loaded assemblies, features, environment variables, etc. It could look similar to this:
public string GetApplicationType()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")))
        return "ASP.NET Core";
    else if (Console.OpenStandardInput() != Stream.Null)
        return "Console";
    // ...
}

It would probably take some iterations to get this right, but maybe it's the best approach.

I see 2 options: 1. in runtime validate what types from libraries available (Type.GetType("FULL_NAME")) (ie whether anything asp.net related and so on). 2. Define constants in project file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793499/defineconstants-in-addition-to-existing-ones-in-csproj which you will be able to check with #if DEFINED_CONSTANT constructions


see also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465111/9492730


Check Environment.UserInteractive to distinguish between running from interactive/noninteractive (e.g. system service) mode. This should work. But assuming same mode (e.g. interactive), you can't really distinguish an asp.net app from console app or winforms app. An app could potentially use all APIs, create web endpoints, create desktop forms and write to console.

It's perfectly possible to run ASP.NET Core from a console app (this happens when debugging), and you can run a console app as a service if you want, so not sure what you are trying to achieve.

I understand why this will never be bulletproof. It's only a best guess. I have also run Web APIs from Windows Services in the past.

Could you ask consumers of this library to add some sort of "flag" to their application that you could use?  Maybe services.AddCustomLogging(AppType.AspNet) or perhaps a CSPROJ constant that would need to be present.  Or are you trying to identify applications that have no knowledge of your library or ability to accommodate it?

Sure, that is an option that I considered as well. Maybe a combination where the user can provide the exact project type and a fallback if they don't.

@ThomasArdal why are you asking for this? All the "types" you mentioned are the same actually - a console with extras. A web app can be a console app that starts the ASP.NET Core pipeline, or it can run under IIS. In a container it can only be a console app running Kestrel. A Windows Service is a common app that's registered to be called by the OS and respond to specific commands. The Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices doesn't even handle commands beyond start/stop

@ThomasArdal I want to enrich some logging data with the application type. this should be the actual question or rather, how to log the hosting/execution environment. ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT won't exist on a production server and all processes have a std in. If your library uses DI you can check if the ASP.NET Core or IIS services are registered. UseIIS for example registers some IIS-specific interfaces

@PanagiotisKanavos The enrichment with application type is indeed why I'm asking. And I'm fully aware that this is not bulletproof. I'm only trying to log the best guess. Many special cases would potentially give the wrong answer. For example, a Web API hosted in a Windows Service would say service, not web. I still think this is the right answer in this case. I don't care what the service does for this piece of info. But the fact that it is running as a service interests me.

You could try following codes to distinguish between these app types.
    public static class ApplicationTypeHelper
    {
        public static bool IsWebApp()
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(a => a.FullName.Contains("Microsoft.AspNetCore"));
        }

        public static bool IsConsoleApp()
        {
            return Environment.UserInteractive
                   && !IsWebApp()
                   && !IsWindowsService()
                   && !IsWpfApp()
                   && !IsWinFormsApp();
        }

        public static bool IsWindowsService()
        {
            if (Environment.UserInteractive) return false;

            //session ID for Windows services is typically 0.
            using (var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                return process.SessionId == 0;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsWpfApp()
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("PresentationFramework"));
        }

        public static bool IsWinFormsApp()
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("System.Windows.Forms"));
        }
    }

